# Private net Miner/Coinbase account changed

Tags: mining, coinbase, private

I set a Private net with Geth.
and use miner.start() to mine blocks.
my default account is 0x59a4155889e72de7846da695672d87f0e6da7332 in the keystore folder.

PROBLEM:
before 3000 blocks, the block's coinbase is 0x59a4155889e72de7846da695672d87f0e6da7332 which is my default account, but when mining for 3000 blocks, the 3001 block's header.coinbase become 0x6ad5c14743b1fb28c012c877824d5b07c0ebc2ed which i have never seen... 
so anybody know why?

Comment: Is miner RPC api enabled in your node? How did you launch your node?

Comment: yes，i did enable my RPC， so you mean someone set the miner via RPC?

Comment: If your node has a public IP and the miner RPC api is enabled then it is possible to change the etherbase using [miner.setEtherbase()](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#miner_setetherbase).

Comment: ok，i see。 some bad guy changed my private net coinbase， via the way you said.